# Array with Class and Subclass null error

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, null, subclass

I am a complete newbie when it comes to programming and my first post so please forgive all my errors in advance. I am trying to figure out why when I println information from an array containing variables from a superclass and subclass I get null and other jargon. I know this specifically has to do with the Ebook subclass I have added, but just seem to be completely stuck the last several days. I hope someone here doesn't mind taking a look at this. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Bookstore2_3
{
public static void main(String args[])
{

    NumberFormat usCurrency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    DecimalFormat simpleformat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#");

    String[] titles;
    titles = new String [5];

    titles [0] = new String ("David Goes to School");
    titles [1] = new String ("No David!");
    titles [2] = new String ("Simple Abundance");
    titles [3] = new String ("The very hungry caterpillar");
    titles [4] = new String ("We are going on a bear hunt");        

    Book sortedBooks[] = new Book[5];
    sortedBooks [0] = new EBook (0075260012l, "David goes to School", "David Shannon", 2010, "Shannon Rock", 12, "www.anything.com", 1);
    sortedBooks [1] = new Book (7423540089l, "No David!", "David Shannon", 2009, "Shannon Rock", 13);
    sortedBooks [2] = new Book (0743200616l, "Simple Abundance", "Sarah Breathnach", 2009, "Scribner", 15);
    sortedBooks [3] = new EBook (78137521819l, "The very hungry caterpillar", "Eric Carle", 2005, "Philomel Books", 14, "http://www.tinyurl.fguopt8u90", 1);
    sortedBooks [4] = new Book (9781416987116l, "We are going on a bear hunt", "Michael Rosen", 2009, "McElderry", 16);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedBooks));

}
} // end class Bookstore

// Begin class Book
class Book
{
public float isbn;
public String title;
public String authorName;
public float yearPublished;
public String publisherName;
public float price;

public Book ()
{
    isbn = 0;
    title = "";
    authorName = "";
    yearPublished = 0;
    publisherName = "";
    price = 0;
}

public Book (float bookisbn, String bookTitle, String bookauthorName, float bookyearPublished, String bookpublisherName, float bookPrice)
{
    isbn = bookisbn;
    title = bookTitle;
    authorName = bookauthorName;
    yearPublished = bookyearPublished;
    publisherName = bookpublisherName;
    price = bookPrice;
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setISBN (float ISBN) //set ISBN
{
    this.isbn = ISBN;
}
public float getISBN () //get ISBN
{
    return isbn;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setTitle (String Title) //set Title
{
    this.title = Title;
}
public String getTitle () //get Title
{
    return title;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setAuthorName (String AuthorName) //set AuthorName
{ 
    this.authorName = AuthorName;
}
public String getAuthorName () //get AuthorName
{
    return authorName;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setYearPublished (float YearPublished)//set YearPublished
{
    this.yearPublished = YearPublished;
}
public float getYearPublished () //get YearPublished
{
    return yearPublished;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setPublisherName (String PublisherName)
{
    this.publisherName = PublisherName;
}
public String getPublisherName ()
{
    return publisherName;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setPrice (float Price)
{
    this.price = Price;
}
public float getPrice ()
{
    return price;
}

} // end class Book

//Begin class EBook
class EBook extends Book
{
public String webSite;
public float discountRate;
public float discountOff;

public EBook (float isbn, String title, String authorName, float yearPublished, String publisherName, float price, String webSite, float discountRate)
{
    super(isbn, title, authorName, yearPublished, publisherName, price);
    webSite = "";
    discountRate = 2;
}
public EBook (String EBookWebSite, float EBookDiscount)
{
    webSite = EBookWebSite;
    discountRate = EBookDiscount;
}   


public void setWebSite (String WebSite)
{
    this.webSite = WebSite;
}
public String getWebSite ()
{
    return webSite;
}
public float discountOff (float discountRate, float price) //method to calculate discount off
{
    float discountOff = discountRate * price;
    return discountRate * price;
}
public String toString ()
{
    return "ISBN: " + isbn + "\n" + "Title: " + title + "\n" + "Author's Name: " + authorName + "\n" + "Year Published: " + yearPublished + "\n" + "Publisher's Name: " + publisherName + "\n" + "Price: " + price + "\n" + "Website: " + webSite + "\n" + "Discount: " + discountRate + "\n";
}

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific with the error than "null and other jargon".

Comment: Don't forget to override the `toString()` method in your `Book` class.

Comment: Wow! Hi everyone and thanks for the really quick feedback already! What I am trying to do is display all of the information within the array. It does compile properly, but when actually running it, anything with a website responds Null and the Discount says Zero. Website and Discount are members specific to the subclass of Ebook so I think it has to do with that, I am just stuck as to how to resolve this.

Comment: There are many other issues in this program all together, but because this is for my own learning experience I am only trying to get past the part I am currently stuck on and hopefully resolving the rest myself. The other jargon that appears when running the class is "Book@1d7e8c5b, Book@5f30b97d"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor

```
webSite = "";
```

should be

```
this.webSite = "";
```

or

```
this.webSite = webSite;
```

Previously you were referencing the constructor parameter named `webSite`, not the instance field. As such, the instance field remained `null`, which is the default value for an instance variable of a reference type.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that's all it was thank you so much for this!

Comment: @CoShark The `Book@1d7e8c5b` is the result of `Object#toString()` method which all classes inherit. You need to override it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I am just trying to figure out the Override concept now. Where would this get placed? If you do not mind showing me.

Comment: @CoShark See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html). Notice your `EBook` class has a method `public String toString()`. Try adding the `@Override` annotation to it. Then try adding the `@Override` annotation to any other method.